# Pass in parameters for javascript click event

Tags: javascript, events, click, bind

I want to run a function within an object on click. In the object's `init` method, I bind a click to "runBFS".

I use `bind(this)` to traversal so I can pass in the context of the object and not lose it to the window.

```
var api = {},
api.init = function () {
  document.getElementById("runBFS").addEventListener(
    "click",
    this.traversal.bind(this),
    false
  );
}
```

I need to pass in a boolean value on click (`traverseNodesBool`) but don't know how to pass it in when using `bind()`

```
api.traversal = function (e, traverseNodesBool) {
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as the second param to bind.

```
document.getElementById("runBFS").addEventListener("click", this.traversal.bind(this, traverseNodesBool);

api.traversal = function(yourBool, e) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

[.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) ,so first parameter is context and rest follows your other parameters, so it would be:

```
this.traversal.bind(this, yourParamHere);
```